# Get Value from Object to Activity/Fragment in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a goal here where I want to create a reusable volley service so I will not add those very long code on my activities. So far here`s what I did.

First I created an object

```
object APICallerUtils {
    fun callAPI(con: Context) {
        val cache = DiskBasedCache(con.cacheDir, 1024 * 1024)
        val network = BasicNetwork(HurlStack())
        val requestQueue = RequestQueue(cache, network).apply {
            start()
        }
        val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(con)
        val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            builder.setView(R.layout.layout_loading_dialog)
        }

        dialog.setCancelable(false)
        dialog.show()

        val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Method.POST,
            "http://192.168.16.107/dynamicapicall/caller.php",
            Response.Listener { response ->
                try {
                    val obj = JSONObject(response)
                    //Log.e("Message",obj.toString())
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    val errorMessage = StringWriter()
                    //Log.e("Message",errorMessage.toString())
                }
                dialog.dismiss()
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { volleyError ->
                //Log.e("Message",volleyError.message.toString())
                dialog.dismiss()
            }) {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                return params
            }
        }
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest)
    }
}
```

And in my activity I call it like `APICallerUtils.callAPI(this)`

My question is the function returns a JSON how can I get that?

**UPDATE**
Sorry for the confusion my goal here is to get the `val obj = JSONObject(response)` everytime I call `APICallerUtils`  so I can assign it in a loop like

```
try {
     val obj = APICallerUtils 
     val array_drink_header = obj.getJSONArray("result")
     val DrinkHeader = ArrayList<drinkwall_header>()

      for (i in 0 until array_drink_header.length()) {
```

Comment: "How can I get that?" How can you get what? Where do you want to get it?

Comment: I want to get `val obj = JSONObject(response)` when I call `APICallerUtils.callAPI(this)` so I can use it on loops

Comment: @Code-Apprentice sorry for the improper question please see the update. thnx

Comment: The main thing to understand here is that the HTTP request is made asynchronously. This means that `val stringRequest  = ...` makes a request object, but the actual HTTP request isn't executed immediately. The request will be executed later and so the response isn't immiedately available when `callAPI()` returns. I suggest you read more about async programming in Kotlin to figure out how to solve this.

Comment: Hopefully the link that I added at the top of your question will point you in the right direction.